# How can I catch errors from chrome and process them in JUnit test

Tags: java, google-chrome, junit, google-chrome-devtools

For instance, I have a java web application running..When I do some actions error appears(little white chrome window - screen below, reproducable). Can I write a test where I'll check if tab appeared or not using **JUnit**.

Screen on imgur: [click!](http://imgur.com/Jg5rjwX)

Comment: Yes you can. But selenium web driver is enough for it. No need of junit.

Comment: @HelpingHands thanks! But I have to do this via JUnit. AFAIK we can use **Selenium** in JUnit. So, **how** i should catch this error?

Comment: For that please check selenium tutorial and try to write code. Then if you get any issue then share that code here with question so we can look at.

Comment: Helpful link : http://www.toolsqa.com/java/junit-framework/junit-test-selenium-webdriver/

Answer (score 1):

you can use selenium framework for ui testing. [Selenium Web Driver Automation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: Well, will **Selenium** allow me to work with this type of error?

Comment: Yes, it will. See documentation of Selenium.